# Experimental results for the measurement of Positron lifetime / Positron decay

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, antimatter, radioactivity, half-life

It is assumed that the positron, being the antimatter particle of the electron, is stable.

I am interested in finding experimental results or experiments which have measured the positron lifetime in a vacuum.

Are there any such experiments which have been performed, and if so which experiments or institutions made lifetime measurements?

Links to any papers would be welcome also.

***EDIT:*** The linked question does not address the question being asked here. The linked question (and answer) **assume** that the properties of antiparticles are the same as particles. There is no discussion of experimental results for the measurement of the positron decay lifetime, which is what this question is specifically about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why an electron and a positron should have the same lifespan?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/672048/)

Comment: What would you assume positron could decay into? Any such decay (to known particles) would violate electric charge, and electric charge conservation is tested to excellent precision.

Comment: I doubt such experiments were performed though (the PDG does not give any reference), primarily because of challenges to avoid annihilations with the experimental setup. Even the "best" vacuum we can obtain in the lab would inevitably have some random atoms flying around, not even mentioning the walls.

Comment: @martino not necessarily. The products of the decay could have the same charge. I had the same theory regarding why this hasn't been done. There is also an additional challenge. The detectors would have to be very low background.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the moderators of this site don't have an understanding of what is the difference between experimental measurements and theoretical predictions, since this question has again been closed.