# Mass of Antiparticles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, mass, antimatter

Why do the mass of anti-particles have to be exactly equal to the particles ?

What I learnt from Srednicki Chapter 23 is that to support charge conjugation symmetry (C-symm) of Lagrangian, mass of particle and anti-particle must be same.

My question is "Is charge conjugation symmetry a universal truth -- proven by experiments, or we still can have some Lagrangians (L) which doesn't support C-symm., where changing + charged particles to - charged in L will not mean m+ = m- ?" What would existence of such a theory mean to our world ?

Comment: C. S. Wu discovered C violation in 1956 but it did not manifest itself as particles and anti-particles with different mass.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is the CPT theorem.

Comment: C is almost maximally violated in the weak interactions.

Comment: For literature, check the [Particle Data Group’s reviews](https://pdg.lbl.gov/) of particle properties, and follow the references for comparisons of particle versus antiparticle masses.

Comment: a related discussion is in this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672048/why-an-electron-and-a-positron-should-have-the-same-lifespan/672106#comment1610174_672106 . If they were found to be different experimentally, this would affect the lifetimes also.